# Java library for searching text in JSON file

Tags: java, json

I would like to search after a given keyword in a big JSON file. Does anybody know a java library for this?

Comment: A JSON string is just that, a string. So just use the normal javascript ability to search the string.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java

Comment: Have you researched anything on your own? How big of a file? Can it be parsed in-memory? What is the file's schema like? Does your keyword need to be found in a field or a value? Please give us more information or we can't properly answer your question.

Comment: I don't know the exact size of the file, it should be about 2 MB. I will solve the memory issues if it is the case, I am just interested if there are any libraries for search. The search string should be found in a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) could help you to parse the json file easily.

Unlike many other JSON libraries, [Gson supports streaming](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming) which means you can examine the file in small chunks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just searching for a keyword, I don't see how the fact that it's JSON requires a special library. This would only help if you were looking for something particular to JSON such as a key or value.

Couldn't you just scan the file line-by-line and search for the substring?

```
public static boolean find(File f, String searchString) {
    boolean result = false;
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(new FileReader(f));
        while(in.hasNextLine() && !result) {
            if (in.nextLine().contains(searchString))
                return true;
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();      
    }
    finally {
        try { in.close() ; } catch(Exception e) { /* ignore */ }  
    }
    return false;
}
```

from http://technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/109-search-for-string-in-text-file-in-java.

Answer (score 0):

You can find json library it [here](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I don't see any search functionalities in this library. It just converts JSON format to Java beans and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Search for JSONArray and JSONObject

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

it's pretty easy to work with them.

Comment: I know JSONArray and JSONObject, but they don't answer my question.