# How to get value for particular key only without reading whole JSON file in Java?

Tags: java, json, file, parsing, search

I need some information for reading a JSON file using Java. I have a sample data in `abc.json` file as following:

```
{
  "id":"abc",
  "name":"abc",
  "otherInfo": {},
  "personalData:[{}]
}
```

I am reading this file as following:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("...")); //the location of the file
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONArray numbers = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("personalData");
```

**My question is** will this above code read the whole file and then give data for ("personalData") key or will just fetch the data for particular key ("personalData"). And, if it fetches the entire's file data, is there any way to just fetch the value of a particular key without reading the whole file?

Comment: It needs to read the file to be able to parse it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson so there is now way to just read the value for specific key directly form file?

Comment: How would that be possible, it is a text file and not a database?

Comment: findParent is your friend http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#findParent(java.lang.String)

Comment: Look for "json streaming parser" which generate events when they parse specific elements ; use them to interrupt parsing once you've read the relevant piece of data. Note that unless you have huge json files I'd avoid doing so.

Comment: If you're on a JavaEE7 platform there's [JsonParser](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html) that suits your needs.

Comment: Here is auseful post: [Java library for searching text in JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691600/java-library-for-searching-text-in-json-file).

Comment: but this streaming will be immutable right?